# cmd cannot find message text for 0x26e

Tags: command-line

```
 :: try to rename the old file
 C:\parentfolder\fix move "program.exe" "program_old.exe"
 The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2 in the message file or System.
:: try a directory listing
C:\parentfolder\fix dir 

The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2 in the message file or System.
.... a file
.... a file
 The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2 in the message file or System.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you copy-paste the `cmd.exe` from the `C:\Windows\System32` folder to someplace else.

Try running the normal command executable instead. (`Start > Run > cmd.exe`)